# Touch input on mobile device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have this script for inputting touches on the mobile device. But it activates only once, I need it to be run until I take my finger off the screen

```
public float speed = 3;


public Rigidbody rb;
public void MoveLeft()
{
    transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
public void StopMoving()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
}
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        float middle = Screen.width / 2;
        if (touch.position.x < middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > middle && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began )
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StopMoving();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to remove the two `&& touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began` portions. This will have the overall if-statement evaluate true as long as there is one finger on the screen.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        float middle = Screen.width / 2;
        if (touch.position.x < middle)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (touch.position.x > middle)
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StopMoving();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but as long as your screen is not constantly changing size, I would recommend moving `float middle = Screen.width / 2;` out of the Update statement since it does not need to be calculated every frame.

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I am impressed I did not see that. Thanks once again